# Calculate the number of times an angle must be repeated for it to complete a full rotation and for it to close

Tags: matlab, math-software, octave

I'm trying to calculate the number of times an angle must be repeated to make a full rotation and become closed.

Example: The internal angle of a pentagon is **108 degrees** and it must repeat **5 times** to complete a rotation and it closes at **540 degrees**.   It closes a 540 degrees because that's when all the sides meet and close. http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/interior-angles-polygons.html

How can I calculate these numbers for arbitrary angles like **72 degrees** or **117 degrees**, etc..

Does anyone know of a way to calculate this

Ps: I'm using matlab/octave thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible for $$\frac{\phi}{2\pi} =: a \in \mathbb{Q}$$
If $a = \frac{p}{q}$ is the irreducible form of $a$, i.e. $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, then the sought value is $q$; the number of performed revolutions is $p$. I don't know of any efficient algorithm for this, especially as MATLAB / Octave work with numeric approximations to the values

`function n=getRev(a)

b=a;

n=1;

while (abs(b-round(b) > 1e-15))

b = b+a;

n = n+1;

end

end`

---

**Code for outer angles:**
`function n=getOuterRev(a)

b=a;

n=1;

k=(n-2)/2;

while (abs(b-k) > 1e-15)

b = b+a;

n = n+1;

k = (n-2)/2;

end

end`

Comment: When I try this by typing in getRev(108) I thought I would get an answer of 5 but I get an answer of 0.  Am I doing something wrong

Comment: @RickT you need to getRev(108/360)

Comment: ok did the getRev(108/360) which gives me 1 not the number 5 I thought it would.  I also did getrev(108/540) which gives me 2 not the number 5 I thought it would.

Comment: I'm afraid the result is correct with $n=1$ as initial value.  ($108 \cdot 5 = 540 = \frac{3}{2} \cdot 360$, the result would be $n=10$)...  
What you expect is another value, because we use the inner angles (sector angles) in the algorithm

Comment: @RickT added a code for outer angles.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula, known as $180* (n-2)$ where n is the number of sides that gives you your answer. For example, in a pentagon,

$180*(5-2)$ = $540$

Comment: I don't think that is what the question is asking (this is the formula for the degrees of each angle in a regular n-gon).

Comment: In that case, use the reverse formula: $(total angle) \over (internal angle)$ $+ 2$

Answer (score 0):

As AlexR alread noted, we need $\frac{\phi}{2\pi}\in\mathbb Q$. So put $\frac{\phi}{2\pi}=\frac{p}{q}$. There is a "complete rotation", if
$$\varphi\cdot n=\pi\cdot k$$
where $n$ is the number of repetitions and $k\in\mathbb Z$.
So
$$\frac pq 2\pi\cdot n=\pi\cdot k\Rightarrow 2pn=kq$$
For any common multiple of $2p$ and $q$, we can choose $k$ and $n$ in a way, such that the equation holds and $2pn=kq$ is this common multiple. So the smallest solution for $2pn$, will be $lcm(2p,q)$, hence 
$$n=\frac{lcm(2p,q)}{2p}=\frac{q}{\gcd(2p,q)}$$

Note, that $108^\circ=\frac{3}{10}\cdot 2\pi$, so $n=\frac{10}{\gcd(6,10)}=\frac{10}{2}=5$.